# What does this signature say?

Tags: 20th-century, europe

I’m having difficulty of reading what this fancy signature or fancy writing says on my great grandfather’s ring? [image][image]

Comment: @drewbenn both actually. I’m very curious of what it means.

Comment: Do you know of any ancestors with those  initials? (BTW the first one may be a J)

Comment: @Spencer Yea my Great grandfather from my grandmother’s side of the family.

Comment: I'm on team J. I've seen some cursive capital G's that look like that, but it was uncommon (I say *was* because cursive is [essentially obsolete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursive#Decline_of_English_cursive_in_the_United_States), and only us oldsters still know it).

Comment: @T.E.D. If what you’re saying is correct then that makes logical sense to me that because my Great grandfather name is James Spence.

Comment: @drewbenn sorry my granny passed away back in The 3rd of January and my family members wear wondering who’s ring was it since my grandmother had them in there my grandfather said.

Comment: @drewbenn I just wanted to know the initial of the ring to see if it’s really my Great grandfather’s ring. What I’ve should of told you in the beginning was when you turn the ring it has a Masonic compass on it. My grandfather said your granny’s dad wasn’t a mason but he thinks his brother was and he can tell back in the day but his name is Ash spence. I’ll show you the picture.

Comment: It's a capital J separated by a line then a capital S.  The other image is the symbol of the Masons.